# Image is truncated after uploading to Cloudinary

Tags: base64, cloudinary

I am new to PHP web service and to Cloudinary's image uploading.

My code is:

`$result=\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("data:image/png;base64,".$strrr);`

Where `strrr` is a base64 encoded string. However, the image isn't completely uploaded, only the first rows of bits appear and the rest of the bits are black.

**This is how it looks:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with the base64 payload? Maybe you could check by saving the base64 payload to a local file and check if the image is valid?